# python list out of index,

Tags: python, list, loops

I finish the implementation but somehow i get the list out of bounds error everytime
This is the assignment description:

> For this example you first need to create and randomly initialize a square grid:
>
> 1. Implement a 2d regular square lattice (i.e. a grid) with 100x100 cells.
> 2. Initialize 40% of cells with agents of type A and place them randomly in the grid (symbolized as 1)
> 3. Initialize 40% of cells with agents of type B (symbolized as 2) and place them randomly in the grid. Please note, 20% of cells remain empty, (symbolized as 0)i.e.
>
> nobody lives in these cells. You will simulate people relocating
> around city in the search for a neighborhood in which they feel happy.
> Agents feel happy if at least 50% of their neighbors are of the same
> type. Each (central) agent has 8 neighboring cells: a cell to the East
> (E), to the West (W), to the South (S), to the North (N), to the
> Southeast (SE), to the Southwest (SW), to the Northeast (NE) and to
> the Northwest (NW). The agents that live on the grid borders have some
> neighbors missing. For example, the agent living in the cell at
> position (0,0), i.e. in the upper left corner has only three
> neighbors: E, SE, and S. The empty cells do not count for calculation
> of happiness. For example, an agent who lives among otherwise empty
> cells is 100% happy, or an agent who lives near 5 empty cells, 2 cells
> of its own type and 1 cell of the other type is 66% happy (2 own type
> agents / 3 occupied cells in total).
>
> Iterate 20 times Calculate happiness for each agent. Relocate
> an unhappy agent to a random empty cell.

I finished the tasks the only problem is I dont know how to run through the loop without getting list out of bounds:

//Lets say the other parts are all right and we have to Iterate 20 times now

```
currentGrid = grid #// safe the current array to another
while number_of_iterations < 20: #// run 20 times to relocte them
    happiness_list = checkHappiness(currentGrid) # check the current happiness and return a list (8000 elements with 0-100 as value)
    runHappiness = 0
    start = 0

    while start < 100: #// run through the array x
        end = 0

        while end < 100: #run through the array y
            boolW = True
            actualGrid = currentGrid[start][end]
            if actualGrid != 0:
                if happiness_list[runHappiness] < 50.00:

   #// if the current position in array is not zero and he is feeling unhappy -> relocate him
                    while boolW:
                        x = random.randint(0,99) #set random position of x
                        y = random.randint(0,99) #set random position of y
    #// check if the random position is zero to be able to relocate him
                        if currentGrid[x][y] == 0:
                            currentAgent = currentGrid[start][end] #// check the currentAgent if he is 1 or 2
                            grid[x][y] = currentAgent #// safe the new position to the array
                            grid[start][end] = 0 #// the old position will be 0
                            boolW = False
                runHappiness += 1
            end +=1
        start += 1
    currentGrid = grid
    number_of_iterations += 1
```

I keep getting this error:

> if actualGrid != 0 and  happiness_list[runHappiness] < 50.00:
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I mean logically it will just run 8000 times since it has only 8000 values inside the list because when I find a zero in the array the "runHappiness" wont incremented only the "end " iterator but somehow the "runHappiness" goes on after 8000. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: how many times does it run before crashing? you work with grids so it means 2d-arrays at least. isn't happiness_list 2d too?

Comment: @bobrobbob HI, actually during the first run in number_of_iterations, the runhapiness run like 4800 times and then he gets stucked there. And no the hapiness_list is a list with happiness values inside of them like the first agent is 40% happy

Comment: @bobrobbob after around 4700 times he stays in the while boolW statement and cant go out maybe it is because of the new grids?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Use the copy() function for lists to get a valid copy of a list versus a reference to the list.

```
currentGrid = grid.copy()
```

or

```
currentGrid = list(grid)
```

#### Answer to your question

User posed question: *I mean logically it will just run 8000 times since it has only 8000 values inside the list because when I find a zero in the array the "runHappiness" wont incremented only the "end " iterator but somehow the "runHappiness" goes on after 8000. Can someone explain this to me?*

#### Consider the following code and its output

```
#Initialize a 2x2 grid of all zeros
grid = [[0 for x in range(0,2)] for y in range(0,2)]

#Assign a new variable to grid
currentGrid = grid

#update grid
grid[0][0] = 1
grid[1][1] = 1

#print the contents of currentGrid
for x, y in currentGrid:
    print("{0} {1}".format(x, y))
>>>
1 0
0 1
>>>
```

#### What is happening here?

currentGrid has the same values as grid! This is because when you assign variables to lists as in 
`list2 = list1`, list2 is actually pointing to the same values as list1. Therefore the exact same values are referenced via list1 or list2.

#### How is this affecting you?

Your code that follows is actually moving `currentAgent` from one coordinate in `currentGrid` to another coordinate in `currentGrid` even though you are referencing the `grid` variable.

```
if currentGrid[x][y] == 0:
    currentAgent = currentGrid[start][end] #// check the currentAgent if he is 1 or 2
    grid[x][y] = currentAgent #// safe the new position to the array
    grid[start][end] = 0 #// the old position will be 0
```

#### The Kick-in-the-Pants

What happens when actualGrid = currentGrid[1][1] and you assign grid[1][2] = currentAgent? The very next iteration of your while end loop will encounter the exact same previous value, and go through the same logic and increment the variable runHappieness. When start and end are low values it is a very high probability that currentAgent will be relocated into an area of the grid that will later be processed again.

#### Conclusion?

You are moving nodes from the upper left-hand corner of your grid to some other coordinate in a lower right-hand corner of the grid where later it will be processed again. Because you increment the runHappieness variable each time you move a node and you are moving nodes multiple times you get your IndexError: list index out of range.